# How do do period query with month, quarter or year?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a web app in Rails 5.
In this app I want to query an Object called Measure that have a Data_at (datetime) attribute. In my UI I let the user select from three different periods (Month, Quarter and Year).

When they select Month next they need to select which month (1 to 12). 
When they select Quarter they next have to select the quarter (1,2,3 or 4). When they select Year they next have to select which year.

I am looking for a way to make this query on the backend (controller and model) based upon the selected data.

When doing the month I think I can use the beginning_of_month and end_of_month.

When doing the quarter I think I can use the beginning_of_quarter and end_of_quarter rails functions but how would such a query look like. The data I have from user is what quarter they selected (1 to 4) and what year they selected.

This is my current try.

**Query**

```
def self.select_data(params)
    if params[:period] == "month"
      month_dates(params[:month], params[:year])
    elsif params[:period] == "quarter"
      quarter_dates(params[:quarter], params[:year])
    elsif params[:period] == "year"

    end
  end
```

**Model methods**

```
def month_dates(month, year)
    date = Time.parse("01-#{month}-#{year}")
    where(date_at: date.beginning_of_month..date.end_of_month)
  end

  def quarter_dates(quarter, year)
    if quarter == 1
      where(date_at: Time.parse("01-01-#{year}")..Time.parse("01-03-#{year}"))
    elsif quarter == 2
      where(date_at: Time.parse("01-04-#{year}")..Time.parse("01-06-#{year}"))
    elsif quarter == 3
      where(date_at: Time.parse("01-07-#{year}")..Time.parse("01-09-#{year}"))
    elsif quarter == 4
      where(date_at: Time.parse("01-10-#{year}")..Time.parse("01-12-#{year}"))
    end
  end

  def year_dates(year)
    date = Time.parse("01-01-#{year}")
    where(date_at: date.beginning_of_year..date.end_of_year)
  end
```

Comment: Is the user required to specify the year when they select month (for example)? If not, what is the result expected to be? January for every year in the database?

Comment: Yes, year is always mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query boils down to a `where(column: Range)` condition:

```
@measures = Measure.where(data_at: selected_period)
```

Then it's a matter of coming up with the right range for your inputs:

```
def selected_period
  case params[:period]
  when "year"
    Date.new(params[:year].to_i).all_year
  when "quarter"
    # It seems like there should be a nicer way to spell this :/
    Date.new(params[:year].to_i, 3 * params[:quarter].to_i - 2).all_quarter
  when "month"
    Date.new(params[:year].to_i, params[:month].to_i).all_month
  end
end
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!